# Azure DevOps - How can I add a stage after a release has been created

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We currently have a release set up like so..

```
DEV ----> QA -----> UAT (Customer 1) ----> Live (Customer 1)
          |
          |-------> UAT (Customer 2) ----> Live (Customer 2)
```

It needs to be set like this since each customer has different UAT and Live dates that they can take upgrades, plus connection strings and ports all different.

This currently works, however, how would I manage if a third customer decided to take the software? I'd need a release definition like this:

```
DEV ----> QA -----> UAT (Customer 1) ----> Live (Customer 1)
          |
          |-------> UAT (Customer 2) ----> Live (Customer 2)
          |
          |-------> UAT (Customer 3) ----> Live (Customer 3)
```

But I am unable to add stages after a release has been created.

I know I can use deployment groups and 'Redeploy' but that restricts us by ensuring the software is deployed at the same time for all customers.

Any advice if you've faced this issue before would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible. Even if it were possible, you wouldn't want the new stages to just be for that release, so you'd end up creating the stages in the release and the pipeline anyway.

However, you said that each customer has their own timelines. From that, I'm guessing that the deployments are manually triggered.

So let's say customers A and B are on release 3. Now you want to add a customer C onto release 3. You would simply create a new release 3 (off of the same build results) and manually push to customer C. Customers A and B won't be affected since the deployments are manually triggered.